# Is there a package of Rawstudio 2.0?

Tags: 11.10, ppa, photo-management

Will [Rawstudio 2.0](http://rawstudio.org/) come to Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 4):

look there: https://launchpad.net/~rawstudio/+archive

I found the package for Oneiric: it is named `2.0-0ubuntu1~oneiric3`

Answer (score 1):

There should be the package for Ubuntu 11.10 because it was added 5 days ago and here is a guide on how to install it:

http://www.lffl.org/2011/04/upgrade-rawstudio-20-su-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

Rawstudio has its own [daily build ppa](https://launchpad.net/~rawstudio/+archive/ppa) but no packages for Ubuntu 11.10.

You can contact them at contact@rawstudio.org and ask them directly since they will be the ones that can provide a better answer.

If you are interested on the software you can also build it from source, it will work as the packages do, for instructions have a look [here](http://rawstudio.org/download.php).